# Heroku express + react + webpack - can't run on server

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, webpack

I have my webpack + ts + express + react application. I can build it locally without any problems. . And everything works, but when i publish it to heroku i've got this:

eb.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-11-06T15:32:36.057014+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 2

2019-11-06T15:32:36.058319+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! v@0.0.0 start: `tsc && node ./build/app.js`

2019-11-06T15:32:36.058526+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 2

2019-11-06T15:32:36.058771+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!

2019-11-06T15:32:36.058897+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the v@0.0.0 
start script.

2019-11-06T15:32:36.059048+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Folder structure

api

- - app.ts

client

- - src
- - tsconfig
- - package.json

tsconfig

package.json

file app.ts

```js
app.use(cors());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));

app.use('/api/posts', postRoutes);
app.use('/api/users', userRoutes);
app.use('/api', errorRoutes);

app.get('/*', (req, res: Response) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build/index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 1646;
app.listen(port, () => {
  // tslint:disable-next-line: no-console
  console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

```js
{
  "name": "v",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.11.2",
    "npm": "5.6.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev:front": "cd client && npm run dev",
    "dev:server": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpileOnly ./api/app.ts",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run dev:server\" \"npm run dev:front\"",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "start": "tsc && node ./build/app.js",
    "clean": "rimraf ./build",
    "build": "tsc && node ./build/app.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm run build",
    "heroku-prebuild": "cd client && npm install"
  },
  "dependencies": { //I Putted evrything here to dependencies
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.30",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0", ....
```

tsconfig

```js
"target": "es6"
    "module": "commonjs"
    "outDir": "./build",
"include": [
    "api/"
  ]
```

package.json client

```js
scripts ...
 "build": "npm run clean && webpack -p ---open --config webpack/production.js",
    "clean": "rimraf build/*",
    "tsc": "tsc --noEmit",
    "lint": "tslint './src/**/*.ts*' --format stylish --project . --force",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server ---open --config webpack/development.js"
```

Comment: HERES my app :https://github.com/bartek-fecko/fullstackapp

Answer (score 0):

Your build process shouldn't be starting up your app.  Change

```
"heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm run build",
```

to

```
"heroku-postbuild": "npm run tsc",
```

That should create the build folder you want.  Then you'll want to add a new file called `Procfile` to the root of your project with this line of code:

```
web: node build/api.js
```

Which tells Heroku how to start up your app.

Comment: Could you help me with another problem.. 
i have: when app try to get users fetch request
VM116:1 GET http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/users/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
error, the data is not avaliable. But it works once, on server and then stopped.

Comment: For some reasons frontend doesn't recognized localhost, so i need to add a proxy in my webpack config and now it works. By the way. I 'm bulding my app locally and send it to heroku becasaue when i tried your approach, i've got app exits with error status 2. 0_o strange. Thx for help.

Comment: Your code should _not_ be referencing localhost.  It should just reference `/api/users`, then let express determine where it should go.

Comment: Also, be sure typescript is in your dependencies in your package.json.  Otherwise it won't get installed in heroku (a lot of people install this globally, which means it won't build in heroku)

Comment: If that doesn't work, try `postinstall` instaed of `heroku-postbuild`